# NSNotificationCenter selector isn't being called with locationKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

I've implemented `locationKit` ([locationKit.io](http://locationkit.io)) SDK into my app.

I have an `NSNotificationCenter` observer which calls two selectors in two different classes (basiclly, pass data from one class to two other classes).

When I used `CLLocationManager` everything worked perfectly but when I switched to `LKLocationManager` just one of the selectors is being called (the selector in the first class is working fine but the selector in the second class isn't being called at all).

When I switch back to `CLLocationManager` everything is working again.

My `LKLocationManager` on `AppDelegate.m`:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.locationManager=[[LKLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.apiToken=@"myAPIToken";
}
```

Creating the observer in `firstGetterClass.m`: (working)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(getArrays:) name:@"callGetArrays:" object:nil];
```

Creating the observer in `secondGetterClass.m`: (not working)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(getArrays:) name:@"callGetArrays:" object:nil];
```

Sending the post notification from `senderClass.m`:

```
-(void)sendAllStoresAndCategories
{
    NSDictionary *arrayDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.arrayToSend,@"arrayToSend", nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"callGetArrays:" object:nil userInfo: arrayDictionary];
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I’m not too sure what help I can provide to you.

It’s really tough without seeing your code how all these pieces fit together or how/why LocationKit could be causing the issue. Here at SocialRadar, we have internal apps using NSNotificationCenter and haven’t seen this issue.

Further, I’m not sure how LocationKit would cause such a problem as our SDK does not touch or alter NSNotificationCenter in any way.

Is your problem more that the callbacks in which you’re firing these notifications are not being called as you'd expect?

It may be useful to look at our [open source sample app](https://github.com/LocationKit/iOS-App/blob/master/LocationKitApp/AppDelegate%2BVisitHistory.swift#L76) which uses LocationKit along with NSNotificationCenter and doesn’t have any issues.

Cheers,
Victor
VP of Engineering, SocialRadar

Comment: Hey Victor,
I've sent you an email :)

Comment: Hi @FS.O I'd love to help you troubleshoot, but you simply haven't given me enough info to do so. If you can send me more info I can help but the info you gave above is just not enough.